# Google DevTools Timeline Panel missing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I open the google DevTools I cant find the Timeline Panel
as described here:

[image]

There is simply no tag. Whats wrong?
I'am on Windows 7 and Chrome 61.0.3163.91

Comment: You're looking at an ancient tutorial. Now it's Performance panel.

Comment: I'am on https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/demos/too-much-layout/index the actual tuts

Comment: Where is the css-coverage?

Comment: Found a [screenshot](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage) using search in the documentation.

Answer (score 70):

The Timeline panel is now called the Performance panel. This change was introduced in Chrome 58. You can see what version of Chrome you're running by typing chrome://version into the URL bar.

I write the official DevTools docs. That doc is old. I need to redirect it to the up-to-date docs, or add a deprecation notice to it.

[Get Started With Analyzing Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) teaches you how to diagnose forced synchronous layouts, using the Performance panel. Note that the workflow and UI are different than the tutorial that you referenced, but the new workflow ultimately achieves the same goal of diagnosing and finding forced synchronous layouts.

Comment: I was looking at the timeline panel in this section: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-problems/#visualize_memory_leaks_with_timeline_recordings However, there is no way to display the memory usage like that anymore, right? I found something called the Performance Monitor, which is close, but a bit small and not really interactive...

Answer (score 10):

The performance panel provides the combined functionality of Timeline and JavaScript CPU profiler

[image: The performance panel provides the combined functionality of Timeline and JavaScript CPU profiler]

The latest version is now

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference